# Decode json on ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, json

Hi I'd like to build a simple json looking like this: `{"Count" : "55", "total" : "125,55"}`

On my vb method i'm doing this to encode it:

```
Dim json As String = "{""Count"" : "" " & intCount & " "", ""total"" : "" " & intTotal & " "" }"
```

But I think Im missing something to escape the quotes, when my browser received it, it looks like this: `{"d":"{\"Count\" : \" 5 \", \"total\" : \" 55 \" }"}`

making it unreadable for jQuery...

any idea how to encode this json in a simple way?

Comment: how are you outputting this to the page ?

Comment: webMethod Public Shared Function then a return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, you would bypass all the syntax nuances all together (its error-prone) and add some flexibility to your app by allowing the framework to serialize (or deserialize) your data for you.

In a nutshell, you would create an object with those properties (count, total,...future additions?) and use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` which can be found in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` namespace.

Here's a tutorial: [How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

MSDN: [DataContractJsonSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)